# How to enable log rotation in Jenkins for weekly?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, logrotate

I am trying to enable the log rotation for jenkins. Because the log file occupied more memory space. Is there any plugins or method to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Job Configuration -->Discard Old Builds:

There is default Log Rotation strategy:

[image: Jenkins log rotation]

I suggest you to click the "Advanced" button to know more about this log rotation strategy.

Comment: It helps me to clear build log, but my requirement is to cleanup the master's log for jenkins in server. By googling i read about to modify  logrotate.d (/var/log/jenkins/access_log) config file. Can you please answer for this?

Answer (score 5):

Other answers here are referring to the logs generated by the individual jobs,
but if you are asking about Jenkins' *main* `jenkins.log` file (generated by the Jenkins-server),
a bug related to that was fixed on **Apr-2015** -
see here:

- [**Add a logrotate definition to the Jenkins Debian package definition** (similar to Apache, cron-apt, aptitude and apt)](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8641)

Also, you can read more about logging in Jenkins, here:

- [Jenkins - Logging](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging)

Answer (score 1):

It's a default Jenkins feature and you do not need a plugin to achieve what you require. Go to job config page and check the flag at "Discard old builds" (it is right under the job's description. Then select log rotation as strategy and specify the '7' as a value for 'Days to keep builds'.

Comment: OP asked about Jenkins system logs, not the job logs.