# Jenkins on windows: How to I enable log rotation for `jenkins.out.log`

Tags: jenkins, logging

We currently run Jenkins on a Windows machine and the system log (`jenkins.out.log` and `access.log`) is growing quite huge. Until now I did not find a way to enable log rotation when running Jenkins on Windows.

The [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610924/how-to-enable-log-rotation-in-jenkins-for-weekly) doesn't answer this question specifically and also mention the job log. My concern is another.

[Official documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging) doesn't state anything, neither does the [the Cloudbees docu](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/221764048-Log-file-rotation)

Answer (score 0):

Corrext, log rotation is not a buit-in feature of Jenkins; not sure why not. Seem to recall reading Koshuke said there was not a portable solution and I guess was not a priority item; seems it's Linux first (where there's a sol'n).

On Linux, it relies on you setting logrotate.

What you need is a [Windows equivalent of logrotate](https://serverfault.com/questions/358172/equivalent-of-logrotate-for-windows).