# Jenkins log getting huge and filling up entire disk space

Tags: linux, jenkins, amazon-ec2

Every week I got surprised by my Jenkins server hitting 100% disk used by Jenkins log.

So I remove the file, and then my disk gets lots of free space again.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        987M   60K  987M   1% /dev
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       32G   32G     0 100% /         <============================= DISK FULL

[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ sudo rm /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log <======= REMOVE LOG FILE

[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        987M   60K  987M   1% /dev
tmpfs           997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       32G   11G   21G  35% /         <============================= FREE SPACE AGAIN
```

My Log Level configs are:

```
Name                | Level
----------------------------------
winstone            | 5
org.apache.sshd     | WARNING
                    | INFO
```

How can I definitively prevent this problem?

Comment: You've tagged amazon-ec2 on the question so I am assuming that is on an ec2 instance? Add an additional EBS disk and then mount that as an additional directory e.g. /opt/jenkins. Then simply configure Jenkins to write to this directory by changing /etc/default/jenkins if you are running a deb based systems or /etc/sysconfig/jenkins on rpm.

Comment: The question has been [asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610924/how-to-enable-log-rotation-in-jenkins-for-weekly) but is not marked as answered, so cannot call this duplicate. Advice is correct. As that user has not been back in 4+ years, consider marking this as correct and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem for anyone running from the war, and even originally some of the packaged installers, see [JENKINS-8641](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8641)

By default, Jenkins did not include system log rotation, so eventually it will fill the disk. Eventually determined by how much you use Jenkins and the disk space available.

This cloudbees doc describes how to use [logrotate](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/221764048-Log-file-rotation). Link to  [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). You can enable even for standalone war execution.

```
/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log {
        weekly
        copytruncate
        missingok
        rotate 52
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
}
```

Normally this file would be found in `/etc/logrotate.d/jenkins` or `/etc/logrotate.d/jenkins-oc`.

You may want to set to rotate daily and retain only a week (rotate 7), or set specific limits based on maxsize or a combination.

You can read more about logging in Jenkins, here:

[JENKINS - Logging](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/)

[JENKINS - Logging Configuration](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logger+Configuration)

See also related [logging Q in superuser](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/12561/13379)

.