# Cleanup Jenkins home directory

Tags: jenkins

We have started to use jenkins from last few months and now the size of home directory is about 50GB. I noticed that size of **Jobs** and **workspace** directories are about 20 GB each. How can I clean them? What kind of strategy I should use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the various Jenkins areas that tend to grow excessively. The key areas are: system logs, job logs, artifact storage and job workspaces. This will detail options to best manage each of these.

### System logs

System logs may be found in `<JENKINS_HOME>/logs` or `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`, depending on your installation. By default, Jenkins does not always include log rotation (logrotate), especially if running straight from the war. The solution is to add [`logrotate`](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/221764048-Log-file-rotation). This Cloudbees post and my [S/O response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64371247/598141) add details.

You can also set the Jenkins System Property [`hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.logsTargetDir`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#hudson-triggers-safetimertask-logstargetdir) to relocate the `logs` outside the `<JENKINS_HOME>`. Why answered later.

### Job Logs

Each job has an option to `[ X ] Discard old builds`. As of [LTS 2.222.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64371247/598141), Jenkins introduced a Global Build discarder ([pull #4368)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/4368#) with similar options and default actions. This is a global setting, Prior to that, job logs (and artifacts) were retained forever by default (not good).

[image: Build Discarder Config]

Advanced options can manage artifact retention (from post-build action, "Archive the artifacts" separately.

---

### What's in Jobs directory?

The Jobs directory contains a directory for every job (and folders if you use them). Inside the directory is the job `config.xml` (a few KB in size), plus a directory `builds`. `builds` has a numbered directory holding the build logs for each retained build, a copy of the `config.xml` at runtime and possibly some additional files of record (changelog.xml, injectedEnvVars.txt). IF you chose the `Archive the artifacts option`, there's also an `archive` directory, which contains the artifacts from that build.

Jenkins System Property, [`jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#jenkins-model-jenkins-buildsdir), lets you relocate the `builds` to outside the `<JENKINS_HOME>`

### Why Relocate logs outside <JENKINS_HOME>?

I would strongly recommend relocating both the system logs and the job / build logs (and artifacts). By moving the system logs and build logs (and artifacts if ticked) outside of `<JENKINS_HOME>`, what's left is the really important stuff to back and restore Jenkins and jobs in the event of disaster or migration. Carefully read and understand the steps "to support migration of existing build records" to avoid build-related errors. It also makes it much easier to analyze which job logs are consuming all the space and why (ie: logs vs artifacts).

### Workspaces

Workspaces are where the source code is checked out and the job (build) is executed. Workspaces should be ephemeral. [Best Practices](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Best+Practices)are to start with an empty workspace and clean up when you are done - use [Workspace Cleanup ( `cleanWS()` ) plugun](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ws-cleanup/), unless necessary.

The OP's indication of a workspaces in the Jenkins controller suggests jobs are being run on the master.  say that's not a good (or secure) practice, except lightweight pipelines always execute on master. Mis-configured job pipelines will also fall back to master (will try find reference). You can set up a node physically running on the same server as the master for better security.

[image: CleanWS config]

You can use `cleanws()` EXCLUDE and INCLUDE patterns to selectively clean the workspace if delete all is not viable.

There are two Jenkins System Properties to control the location of the `workspace` directory. For the master: [`jenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#jenkins-model-jenkins-workspacesdir) and for the nodes/agents: [`hudson.model.Slave.workspaceRoot`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#hudson-model-slave-workspaceroot). Again, as these are ephemeral, get them out of `<JENKINS_HOME>` so you can better manage and monitor.

---

Finally, one more space consideration...
Both maven and npm cache artifacts in a local repository. Typically that is located in the user's `$HOME` directory. If incrementing versions often, that content will get stale and bloated. It's a cache, so take a time hit every once in a  while and purge it or otherwise mange the content.
However, it's possible to relocate the cache elsewhere through maven and npm settings. Also, if running a maven step, every step has the Advanced option to have a private repository. That is located within in  job's workspace. The benefit is you know what your build is using; no contamination. The downside though is massive duplication and wasted space if all jobs have private repos and you never clean them out or delete the workspaces, or longer build times every time if you cleaned. Consider using s the `cleanWS()` or a separate job to purge as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The workspaces can be cleaned after and/or prior any execution. I recommend doing it prior and after an execution. After the build, do it only on successful builds. In case of errors, you can enter the workspaces and check there for any clue. You do it on the pipeline using the CleanWs() command.

For jobs directory you can select on your jobs the amount of time / maximum of executions to store. This is more complicated because it depends on what you want to save. For example if there is a lot of builds and you don't mind deleting that information you could save 10 builds during 30 days . That configuration is on the job configuration under job properties and search for "Discard old builds" and "Days to keep build" and "Max # builds to keep".

My suggestion is that you use larger numbers at first and then you can test how it behaves