# Clean Jenkins Directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I check to discard old build, limit Max of the build to keep in Jenkins and delete the old workspace. However, when I run du -sh /var/lib/* Jenkins directory had 21G. I want under it and list files .I see just 236K. Please advise.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cleanup Jenkins home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455560/cleanup-jenkins-home-directory)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to beung a duplicate question(see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475906/598141)), I hope you are aware `ls -Sh` only lists the space occupied by files and of inodes, if it's a directory. You must run `du -hs` to get the size of a directory.

Could be space by `.m2` (maven local repo), `.subversion` (SVN data, in each dir), plus check the obvious Jenkins dirs: logs, jobs and workspaces.