# How to free up space on a Node in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

So the Jenkins controller's built-in node that I have is running out of disk space.
The error that I am getting is following-

```
Built-In Node (the Jenkins controller's built-in node)
Disk space is too low. Only 1.022GB left on /var/lib/jenkins.

Projects tied to Built-In Node
None
```

But I am not sure how to free up the disk space on it. I attached a picture of the error as well. IS there any way to free up the space on this node?[image]

Comment: I believe one solution would be to blow away targeted build jobs. Is there any "find" script for this?

Comment: Also Is there any way to list all the jobs that use this node? Like any Console scripts that can be run for this?

Comment: It's a bad practice to run jobs on the built-in node; set up a co-located node if a separate VM is not an option. Nevertheless, this should [answer your issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455560/cleanup-jenkins-home-directory).